# Relation of functions satisfying rolle's theorem

Tags: calculus, rolles-theorem

Let a > 1 and f,g: [-a,a] $\rightarrow$ R be twice differentiable functions such that for some c with 0 < c < 1 < a,

f(x) = 0 only for x=-a, 0, a

f$'$(x) = 0 = g(x) only x = -1, 0, 1

g$'$(x) = 0 only for x = -c, c

Then which relation between f and g is possible:$$ f = g' \ or \ f' = g \ or \ f = -g' $$

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The question stays as it was taken from previous year papers.

Answer (score 1):

With Rolle we get

$f'(1)=f'(-1)=0$ and $g'(c)=g'(-c)=0.$

Hence $f = g'$ or $ f = -g'$ is not possible.

Comment: Following that up, that, if f(x) = g'(x). Then f(c) = 0 = g'(c). But f(x) = 0 only at x = -a,0,a and c != a. So f(c) != 0. Therefore, f = g' is not possible. So f' = g is the only possibility. Right?